# Grunt "aborted due to warnings" when too much output is generated

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, istanbul, grunt-istanbul

I work on a NodeJS project and I use `grunt` as task manager. In particular, I use `grunt` to run unit test and generate coverage reports.

The program under test has a configurable feature that allows to generate more or less output in the log (the typical ERROR/WARN/DEBUG selector). I have observed that if I run unit test with grunt with maximum logging verbosity (DEBUG) `grunt coverage` ends with:

```
Aborted due to warnings.
```

However, same grunt command with a less verbose log level (i.e. without touching a single line of code expect the log level configuration) works without problem and I get:

```
Done, without errors.
```

Has `grunt` some kind of "output limit" which when overpassed causes an abort situation? Can that limit be removed or configured anyway?

I'm using istanbul for code coverage. Version information follows (in the case they are useful):

```
$ node --version
v6.12.3
$ npm --version
3.10.10
$ grunt --version
grunt-cli v1.2.0
grunt v0.4.5
$ cat node_modules/istanbul/package.json | grep version
  "version": "0.1.46"
```

(I'm new to grunt so sorry if I'm asking a silly question :)

Comment: You might be able to see where the error is occurring by enabling verbose, debug and stacktraces: `grunt yourTask --stack --debug --verbose > grunt.log`. Then you can review the `grunt.log` file to see what the error was.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I have done what you suggest to generate `grunt.log`. However, I don't see anything special there... Does grunt use some special prefix to print error in the log (so I can narrow down my search in the log file)?